# 301 Redirect: New Domain and URL Structure

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to set up redirects from an old domain to a new one. The URL structure will also be different since we'll be using a different CMS. I need to force HTTPS and non-www.

Is the code below correct for that case scenario?

```
# Needed before any rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Force HTTPS and non-WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.newdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.newdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

## 301 Redirects
# Page to Page
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^collections/product/product-1$ https://newdomain.com/product/product-1? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^collections/product/product-2$ https://newdomain.com/product/product-2? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

What's the difference between the code above and a

```
Redirect 301 /collections/product/product-1 https://www.newdomain.com/product/product-1
```

Is one preferred over the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have it your .htaccess file in following way.

***1st way:*** Fixing OP's attempts here.

```
# Needed before any rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Force HTTPS and WWW to non-www/www URLs.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.newdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

## 301 Redirects
# Page to Page
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^collections/product/product-1$ https://newdomain.com/product/product-1? [R=301,NE,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^collections/product/product-2$ https://newdomain.com/product/product-2? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

---

---

***2nd way:*** Using trick here to convert them into single rule if in case you have only `collections/product/product-1` AND `collections/product/product-2` rules only then try following and save one more condition/rules :)

```
# Needed before any rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Force HTTPS and WWW to non-www/www URLs.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.newdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

## 301 Redirects
# Page to Page
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^collections/product/product-([12])$ https://newdomain.com/product/product-$1? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

***Important points related to OP's question:***

- I have removed your 2nd set of htaccess rules as follows ones. Why because your 1st ruleset itself takes care of www OR non-www both redirection to www URL, so you don't need to keep following ones.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.newdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

- Now coming on one more point, I have added `NE` flag into your Rules for keeping urls in same format(not to convert them hexa form).
- Now coming on your question of Redirect rule `Redirect 301 /collections/product/product-1 https://www.newdomain.com/product/product-1` its simple, if you keep only this 1 line then your https and www will NOT be implemented in case URLs are NOT https or www, so it completely depends on your requirement, if you need to implement https and www then keep htaccess shown above(edited on from your shown attempts). But you need to still have redirect Rule because you are going to new domain, so have it in above shown way only.
- Also have put this in regex `(www\.)?` to match in case www is there(which will be there since we had done redirect previous rules) in condition under your comment `## 301 Redirects`.

***NOTE:*** Either use 1st rules OR 2nd rules one at a time, 2nd one is preferred(if it meets my mentioned suggestion where you are having urls `product-1` OR `product-2`)

Comment: I don't think I had ever seen NE used before, that's great info! Thank you!

Comment: Is there any case scenario where you wouldn't use NE?

Comment: @elisa, yeah if there are no special characters, then you may not use it :)

Comment: @elisa, from documentation of apache `NE|noescape By default, special characters, such as & and ?, for example, will be converted to their hexcode equivalent. Using the [NE] flag prevents that from happening.`

Comment: I just noticed that you edited your answer! I've got many different URLs so in this particular case, it won't always be based on that same structure, although it's good to know that it can be done.

Regarding your first proposition:
Is there a reason why you would repeat the first 3 lines every time for Page to Page redirects? I have about 150 single URLs to redirect so that would be quite a lot of lines.

Comment: @elisa, actually it depends on your requirement if you want to execute that rule for each time checking if HTTPS is applied or not then you have to add it but I don't think so that's needed for all URLs I believe because we are handling it in very first 2 rules. It should be fine even your 1st rule for product-1 wouldn't need it IMHO. Please do let me know if you have any further queries here,cheers

Comment: @elisa, Also I would like to mention, you could take this as a starting point and if you have more questions/queries you could open a new thread with complete details and with your full htaccess file and I could try to help you there too, cheers and happy learning :)